# $http.then callback not being called

Tags: angularjs

I have a $http.post call but the callback function does not get called. I have the exact same code for another call and that one works. Can you see any issues with the following code.

```
var data = {entityIds: $scope.allEntityIds, accountIds: $scope.accountIds};
        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/psi4web/rest/social/posts", data,
                  {params: {filter: $scope.filters, 
                          pageNum: $scope.pageNum, pageSize: $scope.pageSize}})
              .then(function(res) {$log.info("test me")}, onError);
```

For debugging purposes, I added an inline function inside then() as shown above and that doesnt work either. I made sure that the data is being returned by the backend.

Thanks.

Comment: `$log.info(test me")`: that's invalid JS code. Open your web browser console: it should contain an error telling you that the JS code can't be parsed. Leave it always opened while developing.

Comment: So no errors in Network tab, request comes from server with 200 status with correct response?

Comment: look in the browser console and lookout for error logs. If any errors are thrown try follow them for the root cause of issue.

Comment: The missing quotes was just a typo when I copied the code in here. My actual code has the correct syntax. I kept the console open, and there were no errors.

Comment: You're not answering dfsq's question. Did you get a 2xx response from the server? How is onError defined? Have you checked if it is called?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minor details that are keeping you from having success. Corrected code below.

```
var data = {entityIds: $scope.allEntityIds, accountIds: $scope.accountIds};
var myPost = $http.post("http://localhost:8080/psi4web/rest/social/posts", data, {params: {filter: $scope.filters, pageNum: $scope.pageNum, pageSize: $scope.pageSize}});
myPost.then(function(res){
    $log.info("test me");
}, function(){
    onError();
});
```

Comment: Except the missing quotes (which was a typo while posting this question), I don't see much difference between my code and yours. You are storing the promise in a variable and calling then() on it, and I am chaining it. Either should work.

Comment: I never had luck when chaining things so I've adopted this method instead. Also, you don't give a definition of your onError function, which could be where you'll find your reponse. Try replacing the onError call in my code with some debugging code and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks, I did have a definition for my onError function, just didn't paste the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The issue was that I had one .jsp page load the other while this http call was being processed and that was wiping out the $scope in my .js script which was being shared by both the jsp pages. Basically, my structure of files and loading things wasn't right (being a newbie to angularjs)

Answer (score -2):

You may have forgotten to inject the dependency on `$q` which is responsible for providing `$promise`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. I never had to inject it before, and similar code in the same script file works for other calls.

Comment: @enkay Got it, people already punished me with the downvotes :)